# Intuitive explanation for why the 15 and 290 Theorems should be true

Tags: number-theory, intuition, quadratic-forms

I recently read about the remarkable [15 and 290 theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems), the second of which states that any positive definite integral quadratic form represents all positive integers iff it represents all positive integers $\leq 290$. (The 15 theorem says that, if such a form can be represented by a symmetric *integer* square matrix (arbitrary integer quadratic forms can correspond to half-integer symmetric matrices via (half) the Hessian), it suffices to consider the positive integers $\leq 15$.)

Is there any reason why we should expect this theorem to be true? I doubt there's a concrete reason to expect $15$ or $290$ in particular to be the "cutoff" points - for example, $33$ is the [largest integer](http://oeis.org/A047701) that is not expressible as the sum of five positive squares, but as far as I know there isn't a particular "reason" why (one can prove that all large enough $n$ can be and then can manually check the rest) - so I guess I'm looking for a reason why such a cutoff should exist:

> Why should there be a positive integer $N$ so that a quadratic form reaching all positive integers $1\leq n\leq N$ implies its universality?

Comment: you have not described the distinction correctly. See http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Bhargava_2000.pdf  Also lots of other things at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Comment: @WillJagy Is my description correct now? I am not very knowledgeable about this topic, so I'm not sure if I'm understanding the distinction correctly.

Comment: no. It is always a symmetric matrix.  A calculus description: let $A$ be half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives. Bhargava considered those cases when $A$ has all integer entries. Later, Bhargava and Hanke allowed $A$ to have some off-diagonal entries that are not integers, rather odd integers divided by $2.$ Conway introduced the phrases "Integer-matrix" and "Integer-valued"

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the clarification. I believe I was missing the fact that the associated matrix is *always* symmetric (as it is half the Hessian), and thus thought the defining condition was that the matrix could be made symmetric while remaining integer.

Comment: It appears the brief articles by Conway and Bhargava amount to the best intuition. Conway does point out that he knew the existence of a finite bound owing to work of Duke and Schulze-Pillot. I now think this original ingredient has not been published anywhere. After the fact, Bhargava  proved finiteness for any similar such problem; for example, Jeremy Rouse published on the positive forms that represent all odd numbers, but are allowed to miss some even numbers.

Comment: one hour talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JybQ-6OTrLQ